# mockito throwing null pointer exception on Mocked Object

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito, testng

Am new to mockito. I did lot of debugging yet am unable to find the solution. My test is throwing null pointer exception for one of the mock object method call where as it is passing for another mocked object. Below is my code

```
public class POServiceImpl implements POService {
    private final PODao poDao;
        
    @Inject
    public POServiceImpl(PODao poDao){
        this.poDao = poDao;
    }
    @Autowired
    CCPOService ccPOService ;
  
    @Override
    public Set<String> getPO(UUID a, UUID b) {
        Set<String> po= poDao.getPO(a, b);
        Set<String> ccpo= ccPOService.getPO(a, b);
        return Stream.concat(ccpo.stream(), po.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    
}

public class CCPOServiceImpl implements CCPOService {
    private final CCPODao ccpoDao;
        
    @Inject
    public POServiceImpl(CCPODao ccpoDao){
        this.ccpoDao = ccpoDao;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<String> getPO(UUID a, UUID b) {
        return ccpoDao.getPO(a, b);
    }
}
```

My Test class is as follows

```
@Test
public class POServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    PODao poDao;

    @Mock
    CCPOService ccpoService;
    
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeMethod() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testPO() {
      final POService porderService = new POServiceImpl(poDao);
      Set<String> res = new HashSet<String>();
      res.add("PO");
      Set<String> res1 = new HashSet<String>();
      res1.add("CCPO");
      when(poDao.getPO(UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"), UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"))).thenReturn(res);
      when(ccpoService.getpo(UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"), UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"))).thenReturn(res1);
      Set<String> result = porderService.getPO(UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"), UUID.fromString("6af27ba7-b668-4571-b673-4a79fc203429"));
      Assert.assertEquals(res.contains("PO"), result.contains("PO"));
      Assert.assertEquals(res.contains("CCPO"), result.contains("CCPO"));
    }
}
```

Test case is giving right mocked Set object for `Set<String> po= poDao.getPO(a, b);` , but it is throwing null pointer exception for line `Set<String> ccpo= ccPOService.getPO(a, b);`
I believe @autowired ccPOService object is null.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Ofcourse it will throw a `NullPointerExcedption` you never assign the `ccPOService` field anything, so it will remain `null`. Instead make `POService porderService` a field and annotate with `@InjectMocks` so it will automatically create an instance and assign the mocked objects to its field and constructor (or just injec both through the constructor which is even better!).

Comment: @injectmocks helped. thanks